# Remote data transfer in a few km wide range

Tags: networking, modules

I am working on a project where the pi is operating on a wide range.
I need a reliable real-time connection between my PC and the pi itself.

What i was thinking about:

-radio ×not an option, because there are a lot of buildings and trees, and the wattage should be over legal range.

-mobile data with a gsm module (is that even possible?) ×more bottom

*The PI is sending reports(gps, etc), and the PC is sending commands(such as abortion, forced camera or buzzer feedback, etc.) to the pi.
If it is possible to use mobile data, am i able to build a peer-to-peer communication without any problems related to port forwarding, etc?

I am sending only a few bytes each second, so i don't need a very quick bandwidth, but reliability is more than important.

Comment: we don't know if you are able to build it ... i think that you are the only one who knows your capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into iot? LoraWan could be an answer if the data packets are small enough.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7n8t62anxIQ

I believe this may be an option. Dig in, good luck!